# Keycloak doesn't work properly when clustered on Kubernetes and sometimes get 400 when user tries to login with authorization code flow

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, keycloak, kubernetes-ingress

I running Keycloak 11 embedded with spring boot. I made clustering changes by reading a lot of documents and googling my requirement. So, I did it with the `DNS_PING` protocol.
The problem is that when a user tries to log in with the front-end application sometimes gets a 400 error with `{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Code not valid"}` response and sometimes gets access token successfully.

I created my project based on this GitHub repository:

https://github.com/thomasdarimont/embedded-spring-boot-keycloak-server

Here are my configurations and running behind Kubernetes and Ingress:

**infinispan.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<infinispan
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:10.1 https://infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-fragment-10.1.xsd"
        xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:10.1">

    <jgroups>
        <stack-file name="jgroups" path="${jgroups.configfile:jgroups_dns.xml}"/>
    </jgroups>

    <cache-container name="keycloak">
        <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
        <local-cache name="realms">
            <memory/>
        </local-cache>
        <local-cache name="users">
            <memory/>
        </local-cache>
        <local-cache name="authorization">
            <memory/>
        </local-cache>
        <local-cache name="keys">
            <expiration max-idle="3600000"/>
            <memory/>
        </local-cache>
        <replicated-cache name="work"/>
        <distributed-cache name="sessions"/>
        <distributed-cache name="authenticationSessions"/>
        <distributed-cache name="offlineSessions"/>
        <distributed-cache name="clientSessions"/>
        <distributed-cache name="offlineClientSessions"/>
        <distributed-cache name="loginFailures"/>
        <distributed-cache name="actionTokens">
            <expiration interval="300000"/>
            <memory/>
        </distributed-cache>
    </cache-container>

    <cache-container name="server" default-cache="default">
        <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
        <replicated-cache name="default">
            <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
        </replicated-cache>
    </cache-container>

    <cache-container name="web" default-cache="dist1">
        <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
        <replicated-cache name="sso">
            <locking/>
            <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
        </replicated-cache>
        <distributed-cache name="dist1">
            <locking/>
            <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
            <persistence>
                <file-store/>
            </persistence>
        </distributed-cache>
        <distributed-cache name="routing"/>
    </cache-container>

    <cache-container name="ejb" default-cache="dist2">
        <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
        <distributed-cache name="dist2">
            <locking/>
            <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
            <persistence>
                <file-store/>
            </persistence>
        </distributed-cache>
    </cache-container>

    <cache-container name="hibernate">
        <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
        <local-cache name="local-query">
            <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
            <memory/>
        </local-cache>
        <invalidation-cache name="entity">
            <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
            <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
            <memory/>
        </invalidation-cache>
        <replicated-cache name="timestamps"/>
    </cache-container>


</infinispan>
```

**jgroups_dns.xml**

```
<config xmlns="urn:org:jgroups"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:org:jgroups http://www.jgroups.org/schema/jgroups.xsd">

    <TCP bind_port="7600"
         sock_conn_timeout="2000"
         send_buf_size="640000"/>
    <PING/>

    <dns.DNS_PING dns_query="${jgroups.dnsping.dns_query:cluster-keycloak-headless}"
                  discovery_rsp_expiry_time="60000"/>

    <MERGE3/>

    <FD_SOCK start_port="57600"/>

    <FD_ALL2 timeout="9000" interval="3000" />

    <VERIFY_SUSPECT/>

    <BARRIER />

    <pbcast.NAKACK2 use_mcast_xmit="false"
                    use_mcast_xmit_req="false"
                    xmit_interval="100"
                    xmit_table_num_rows="50"
                    xmit_table_msgs_per_row="1024"
                    xmit_table_max_compaction_time="30000"
                    resend_last_seqno="true"
                    />

    <UNICAST3 xmit_interval="100"
              xmit_table_num_rows="50"
              xmit_table_msgs_per_row="1024"
              xmit_table_max_compaction_time="30000"
              conn_expiry_timeout="0"/>

    <RSVP/>

    <pbcast.STABLE stability_delay="1000"
                   desired_avg_gossip="50000"
                   max_bytes="1M"/>

    <pbcast.GMS
            print_physical_addrs="true"
            print_local_addr="true"
            join_timeout="1500"
            view_ack_collection_timeout="8000"/>

    <MFC max_credits="2M"/>

    <FRAG3/>


    <pbcast.STATE_TRANSFER />

</config>
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM registry.kian.digital/infra/eclipse-temurin:11-jre-focal
ARG JAR_FILE
ADD ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
EXPOSE ${SERVER_PORT}
```

**headless-service**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: kd-keycloak
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: uat
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: headless
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: kd-keycloak
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: heimdall
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.0.0
    helm.sh/chart: heimdall-1.0.67
    run: kd-keycloak
  name: kd-keycloak-headless
  namespace: uat
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: http
  - name: jgroups0
    port: 7600
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 7600
  - name: jgroups1
    port: 7601
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 7601
  - name: jgroups2
    port: 7602
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 7602
  - name: jgroups3
    port: 7603
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 7603
  - name: jgroups4
    port: 7604
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 7604
  - name: jgroups5
    port: 7605
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 7605
  - name: jgroups6
    port: 7606
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 7606
  - name: jgroups7
    port: 7607
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 7607
  - name: jgroups8
    port: 7608
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 7608
  - name: jgroups9
    port: 7609
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 7609
  - name: jgroups10
    port: 7610
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 7610
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: kd-keycloak
    app.kubernetes.io/name: heimdall
    run: kd-keycloak
  type: ClusterIP
```

**helm values file**

```
metrics:
  jmx:
    enabled: false

service:
  port: 8083

healthCheckUrl: "/actuator/health"
replicaCount: 3

extraArg:
  - -Djgroups.configfile=jgroups_dns.xml
  - -Djgroups.dnsping.dns_query=cluster-keycloak-headless.uat.svc.cluster.local
  - -Djgroups.tcpping.initial_hosts='node1[7600],node2[7600],node3[7600]'
  - -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

extraConfig:
  SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: uat
  SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS =(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=oradb)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=sdw)(GLOBAL_NAME=sdw)(SERVER=DEDICATED)))
  SERVICE_BASE_DOMAIN: "https://uat.myproject.com"

volumeMount:
  - configMapName: "keycloak-key"
    name: jwt-key
    mountPath: /kclk

ingress:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: cookie
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port   $server_port;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-path: /
  hosts:
    - domain: uat.myproject.com
      defaultSubdomains: false
      tls:
        enabled: true
      paths:
        - /(auth/.*)
        - /(api/.*)
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.rgh</groupId>
    <artifactId>kd-keycloak-services-boot</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <properties>
        <start-class>com.rgh.keycloak.MyApp</start-class>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <oracle.driver.version>19.15.0.0.1</oracle.driver.version>
        <oracle.ndriver.version>19.3.0.0</oracle.ndriver.version>
        <keycloak.version>11.0.1</keycloak.version>
        <resteasy.version>4.7.4.Final</resteasy.version>
        <infinispan.version>10.1.8.Final</infinispan.version>
        <jgroups.version>4.2.20.Final</jgroups.version>
        <smallrye-metrics.version>3.0.3</smallrye-metrics.version>
        <liquibase.version>3.5.4</liquibase.version>
        <auto-service.version>1.0.1</auto-service.version>
        <libphonenumber.version>8.12.21</libphonenumber.version>
        <jedis.version>3.3.0</jedis.version>
        <simplecaptcha.version>1.2.2</simplecaptcha.version>
        <logstash-logback-encoder.version>5.3</logstash-logback-encoder.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
        <httpclient.version>4.5.13</httpclient.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>${httpclient.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jgroups.kubernetes</groupId>
            <artifactId>jgroups-kubernetes</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-servlet-initializer</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
            <artifactId>infinispan-core</artifactId>
            <version>${infinispan.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jgroups</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jgroups</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jgroups</groupId>
            <artifactId>jgroups</artifactId>
            <version>${jgroups.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.auto.service</groupId>
            <artifactId>auto-service</artifactId>
            <version>${auto-service.version}</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-adapter-core</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cn.apiclub.tool</groupId>
            <artifactId>simplecaptcha</artifactId>
            <version>${simplecaptcha.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>${jedis.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
            <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
            <version>69.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.24</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.eloyzone</groupId>
            <artifactId>jalali-calendar</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.libphonenumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>libphonenumber</artifactId>
            <version>${libphonenumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc10</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>${oracle.driver.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>orai18n</artifactId>
            <version>${oracle.ndriver.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-dependencies-server-all</artifactId>
            <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                    <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.smallrye</groupId>
                    <artifactId>smallrye-metrics</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>kd-keycloak</finalName>
        <defaultGoal>spring-boot:run</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-info</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <excludeDevtools>true</excludeDevtools>
                    <requiresUnpack>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
                            <artifactId>keycloak-connections-jpa</artifactId>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
                            <artifactId>keycloak-model-jpa</artifactId>
                        </dependency>
                    </requiresUnpack>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-resources</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/classes</outputDirectory>
                            <useDefaultDelimiters>false</useDefaultDelimiters>
                            <delimiters>
                                <delimiter>#</delimiter>
                            </delimiters>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/resources/</directory>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>config/*.yml</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/resources/</directory>
                                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>config/*.yml</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>docker-resources</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/docker/</directory>
                                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>**/*.yml</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <tagNameFormat>v@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
                    <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                    <releaseProfiles>releases</releaseProfiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: your problem solved ?

Comment: After much research and talking with the experts in this category, I recognized that using a key embedded with the spring boot is not a reasonable solution for a production environment because you cannot find a proper Helmchart configuration with this setup. 
So, I changed my mind and decided to use it standardly.
However, the problem should be related to the environment's DNS ping protocol and network infrastructure.
Also, ensure that you run a headless service when clustering the Keycloak.